# (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): Host desconocido

Tags: maven

He eliminado un repositorio por error que tenía en `GitHub` y ahora no sé como actualizar el nuevo que he realizado en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) porque me sale varios errores:

> No plugin found for prefix 'javafx' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\User.m2\repository), spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone), spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

Después como he eliminado este repositorio creé el nuevo y ahora me sale esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, he agregado las dependencias de `Bootstrap` con la **versión 5.3.2**, `font-awesome` **versión 6.4.0**, `jQuery` **versión 3.7.0**, `popper.js`  **versión 2.11.7**, `webjars-locator` **versión 0.47** pero  me da un error, me dice que no han sido descargadas, como las podría descargar?

Para finalizar, antes me dada este error, como hago para solucionarlo?

> [20:05] MENDOZA GALVEZ WILLIAM JAVIER
> Failed to execute goal on project tienda: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tiendaAutos:tienda:jar:1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:5.3.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:5.3.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.webjars:bootstrap:pom:5.3.1 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.webjars:bootstrap:pom:5.3.1 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): Host desconocido (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): Unknown host Host desconocido (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) -> [Help 1]
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
> <https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:k6S8ls5O15q69IZNZquJTHNzVbJwCuU3RWbITclATmg1@thread.tacv2/1696615531254?tenantId=dde2fb8f-d8e0-445e-b851-e69c198c1e59&groupId=c3087c93-8e3d-40de-aa29-fbd636fa8022&parentMessageId=1694300851392&teamName=Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web y Patrones Campus Virtual 2023 Tercer Cuatrimestre LAB:V (11am-2pm) [NA] Grupo No.12&channelName=General&createdTime=1696615531254&allowXTenantAccess=false>

Muchas gracias a todos los que me puedan ayudar, sería de mucha ayuda ya que he estado buscando por todo lado y nada me soluciona, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Céntrate en un solo problema_. Además, pon un título descriptivo: "error de netbeans" no da pistas acerca de tu problema. Recuerda que con un título descriptivo y una pregunta bien redactada, lograrás atraer atención a tu pregunta.

Comment: posiblemente relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/608153/error-con-maven-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-unknown-host-host-desconoc