# error con Maven: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 Unknown host Host desconocido

Tags: java, maven

Por favor tengo un error al momento de crear un proyecto web de java con maven, el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:3.2.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:3.2.1 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:3.2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Host desconocido (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unknown host Host desconocido (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: